# How to generate a 3D landscape from a file

Tags: file, 3d, landscape, representation

I would like to know how to generate a 3D render from a really simple file.
In this file there is triplet of coordinates (`{x, y, z}`) that represent the height at a specific point, but there is something like 4 at 8 points for a `10000*10000` map.

The mounts that this points represent needs to be blunt, I mean that I can't place pyramids on the landscape.

My question is, how to make this?

I've been thinking about make a greyscale png (heightmap) and give it to unity.

**PS**: The engine should not provide a physics engine.

**PSS**: I can do this in any language and with any library

Comment: Are your points on a grid or scattered randomly?

Comment: My points are precise points, so they are on a 10000*10000 grid. But i can't know where they are in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single way of mapping a random set of samples to a regular grid (which may be displayed as a greyscale graphic) - it really depends on the nature of your data and what you want to do with the end result.

There's a good overview [here](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc95/to100/p089.html) which describes the common techniques used in GIS applications.  The easiest one to implement is "Inverse Distance Weighted" where you calculate the height at each grid point as a weighted sum of the closest sample points.  The other techniques like "kriging" give better results, but are much more involved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried interpolation.

I guess this might solve your problem.
Have a look at this [Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation)